# Getting Global Rotation position of object in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

Just like we have `getWorldPosition()`, is there a way we can get the absolute Rotation angle of an object. This will be relevant when the object is under another object; both of which could be rotated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `matrixWorld` property on objects and use the [setFromRotationMatrix](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Euler.setFromRotationMatrix) function on Euler to get the angles:

```
// make sure the matrix world is up to date
obj.updateMatrixWorld();

// extract the rotation matrix
const rotMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
obj.matrixWorld.extractRotation(rotMat);

// extract the rotation
const euler = new THREE.Euler();
euler.setFromRotationMatrix(rotMat);
```

There are equivalent function for [quaternions](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix)

Hope that helps!